# Laravel 8 not translating validation attributes

Tags: localization, laravel-8, recaptcha

I am trying to localise the messages in my form validation using Laravel's validate() function, as follows:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'bail|required|email',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
```

In my lang/en.php etc files I have translations for 'required', as follows:

```
'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
```

And I have an entry in the attributes array, as follows:

```
'attributes' => [
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'Recaptcha',
],
```

However, the translated attribute does not get called in any of the languages.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works if you change the validator to facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'bail|required|email',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
]);
```

And return the erros with `$validator->messages()->getMessages();`.